# testing for string-equality without the string library

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I have code written that I want to see if two char* 'strings' are equal. I have written print statements in the code to help me debug it.

Basically, the commands array is: [a, b, null]

and the cmd the user input can be anything, but if it is a, b, or null then we want to get inside the if statement.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    printf("cmd.name = : %s\nCommand = %s\n", cmd->name, commands[i]);
    if (cmd->name == commands[i]){
        printf("inside if\n");
        valid = 1;
    }
}
```

Its printing out:

```
cmd.name = : a
Command = a  
cmd.name = : a
Command = b
cmd.name = : a
Command = (null)
```

So in the first instance a should be equal to a right? Why is it not going inside the if statement?

Comment: You're testing whether the addresses are the same, not whether the contents are the same. Use `strcmp()` to compare the contents of strings.

Comment: I cannot use the string library

Comment: @user93110 then write your own strcmp-like function. Not being able to use the standard library does not make pointer comparison work to compare the contents of strings.

Comment: Then write a loop comparing the characters, like `strcmp` does.

Comment: I very much doubt that you can't use this library...

Comment: its a hw assignment im working on

Comment: `char*` isn't a string, not even a C-"string", it is just a **pointer** to at least one `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use the string library, you will have to implement your own strcmp function.

A char*, as a type, is only a pointer, i.e. it stores an address. Then the simple '==' will compare addresses, which is not what you want.

A simple strcmp function can be:

```
int myStrcmp(const char *str1, int size1, const char *str2, int size2)
{
   int i = 0;

   if(size1 != size2)
      return -1 //different strings

   for(i = 0; i < size1; i++)
   {
       if(str1[i] != str2[i])
           return -1; //different strings
   }

   return 0; //same strings
}
```

The trick here is that you have to know somehow what are the string sizes. If you can't use the string library, I imagine you can't use strlen() as well.

Comment: @user93110 I updated the code so it compares only strings with the same size

Comment: This implementation cannot be called a "strcmp" equivalent because the return values don't match. Here you only return -1 or 0, while the original strcmp can also return 1 depending on the lexicographical order of the strings.

Comment: @SirDarius actually it should return <0 or >0 depending if the mismatched character of the first string comes before or after the one on the second string (on the alphabet). But this is just an example. His problem requires more tweaking to this function.

Answer (score 0):

The char* represent a pointer to the first character of a string, so by testing cmd->name == commands[i] you test if name has the same address as commands[i]. To compare two strings you can use the strcmp function of the standard library (string.h) and if the function return 0 your two strings are equal.

Edit : If you can't use the string library then write a simple loop. During your loop, if you find a character different between the two strings you return a wrong value (by example 0) and if you can go to the end of your strings without finding differents characters then you return a true value (by example 1)